# OrientDB merging vertices together if they have an outgoing edge to the same vertex

Tags: cluster-analysis, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

So I would like to group vertices together based on their outgoing edges.
If A --> C and B --> C
I would like to merge A and B into a single vertex but somehow keep the labels, A , B for future reference (so that I can identify which vertices were merged together)
Is there a built in way in OrientDB to do this, or would i need to write something custom?

This is usually referred to as cluster-analysis, or graph clustering

Comment: According to me you need to write something custom to get what you want

Comment: That is not clustering. It's a simple **group by** destination operation.